# Why is jQuery UI widget.js setting a height on my window?

Tags: jquery, refactoring, widget

I'm updating a mess of JavaScript over here and I'm trying to find out why my div is having it's height overridden.

I'm trying to set the options of a custom widget so the width of the div is 200. Before the call ever gets to my custom widget, it goes through jquery.ui.widget.min.js where somewhere along the line both "clientHeight" and "offsetHeight" are being set to an undesirable absolute pixel number.

This is the call:

```
$popup.module("option", "dialog", { width: settings.width });
```

Any ideas? Is there an option that you can set to make widget.js not modify the height at all?

EDIT: I've stepped further into the issue and I've discovered that the height is getting set within the first few lines of $.widget.bridge. Does anyone know why a height would be getting set there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height is probably set to [give layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) to your element, in order to work around numerous Internet Explorer quirks.